# Integrating Optimizely with Adobe Analytics

Tags: node.js, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, optimizely

I'm trying to Integrating Optimizely with Adobe Analytics. I have followed along with this guide: https://help.optimizely.com/Integrate_Other_Platforms/Integrating_Optimizely_with_Adobe_Analytics with no success.
The props(prop51) and evars(eVar51) that i'm choosing via the experiment integrations in Optimizely are never sent. I check via the wasp chrome add-on and via the Adobe account. 
All other data (props & eVars) that we set manually are sent.

We are not using `s_code.js` but `AppMeasurement.js` version: 1.5.1. I don't know if we are using custom s variable. I guess not. So I have follow the guide and used:
`window.optimizely.push("activateSiteCatalyst");` with no success.

I have also tried:  `window.optimizely.push(['activateSiteCatalyst', {"sVariable": s_c_il[0].account)}]);` where `s_c_il[0].account` holds the account name, but with no success. 
Tried following this guid as well: http://digitalinsightsworld.com/tag-manager/dtm/optimizely-implementation-check-list-adobe-sitecatalyst/

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong? Or how to go forward?

Br,
Johan

Comment: There is no way to really help you without seeing the page where you are having the issue, but I know from experience it's more than likely a timing issue between optimizely http request response that pushes the campaign info to the AA variables vs. AA making it's tracking call (`s.t()` call).  One way to verify is to type the AA variable into the js console after page load. If you see it has the value then that's confirmation about timing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... We're using AngularJS 1.4.x. The default value for sVariable is 's'.  Generally stated, Optimizely expects window.s to be the omniture object.  Angular abstracts this object to its own injectable item, and is therefore not a standard DOM/element off window.  My quick hack was to set window.s = s from within the Omniture directive.  I'm still working out the best location to do this assignment, but I can verify that I now see the custom eVar for Optimizely outgoing in our Omniture call (using Omnibug).  Hope this helps!